# Can I run a binary file that is Mach-O executable i386 on linux?

Tags: linux, executable, mach-o

I have a program that is Mach-O executable i386 and I was hoping to run it on a linux server. Is this possible?? If so, how? I can't see, to figure this out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no working Mach-O loader for Linux.