# what are the alternatives for running a Mach-O 64-bit binary file on a linux machine?

Tags: linux, macos

**step 1:**
am running on a 64 bit linux machine.
(command): `uname -a`
(result): `Linux ****** 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux.`

**step 2:**
i checked the file type of the "binary file" i want to run.
(command): `file` keymaker
(result): `keymaker: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable, flags:<NOUNDEFS|DYLDLINK|TWOLEVEL|PIE>`

**step 3:**
i made the "mach-o" file executable by changing file permissions.
(command): `chmod +x` keymaker

**step 4:**
i run the "binary file".
(command): ./keymaker
(result): `bash: ./keymaker: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

**step 5:**
When i searched on *stack overflow* for a similar problem i found one but it said that:
(Answer): There is currently no working Mach-O loader for Linux.
(Reference): [Can I run a binary file that is Mach-O executable i386 on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205986/can-i-run-a-binary-file-that-is-mach-o-executable-i386-on-linux)

**step 6:** i have a "*linux version*" of an application installed on my linux machine, but i need to run this "keymaker file" to provide me with a "license key".
And i don't want to install a full (4GB +) MAC OS operating system probably in a virtual machine just to run a simple binary file.
I understand this is a MAC OS file but my theory was that since we can use the "`wine` **application**" for Windows OS applications on linux, there must be alternatives as well for MAC OS needs.

Comment: There is no such solution and even if there were you have no guarantee that it would work with that file, just as `wine` only _sometimes_ and often only _partially_ works. The issue is not the executable format, but the underlying operating system resources that are expected by that "simple binary file", especially if you consider all the different types of operating systems. Note that iOS is _not_ Mac OSX, they are quite different.

Comment: I still believe there is a solution may be basing on the fact that there is probably a Mach-o loader for linux written by **Shinichiro Hamaji**...... on the heading "**Other implementations**" Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O

Comment: As said above: loading the executable does not help. You lack the operating system services.

Comment: @arkascha, thanx for the clarification about iOS and Mac OSx being different.......i thought all along that they were the same

Comment: @arkascha, do you mean that this will **only** be successful if i run this "binary file" on a Mac OSx operating system ?

Comment: That I cannot tell you. It obviously depends on what operating system services and/or resources that application expects and uses. Once more: it seems you think that all you need for a successful usage of some "binary file" is to load it into memory. That is _not_ the case. Even a statically linked binary _expects_ different services and/or resources to be available.

Answer (score 5):

The answer referenced in your question is from 2010. Unfortunately, it seems that it is still of actuality.

The link you gave in comment is a little more interesting because it links to the [Darling](http://www.darlinghq.org/) project that declares

> Darling is a translation layer that allows you to run unmodified macOS binaries on Linux. In its nature, it is similar to the well-known Wine project.

Wow exactly what you asked! But it looks to still be in early stages and not aimed at end users:

> At this point, does not yet run macOS application with a GUI.

TL/DR: you should try the Darling project. Whether it is able to start your program is far from sure, but it seems to be your best bet, mainly if your prog does not use a GUI.